# How to loop through year and month in a R function

Tags: r

I have a web scraping function which takes the year(term) and month(term2) and returns the news headlines as a dataframe:

```
news <- function(term, term2) {
  
  html_dat <- read_html(paste0("https://news.google.com/search?q=site%3%2F",term,"%2F",term2,"&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen"))

  news_dat <- data.frame(
    Title = html_dat %>%
      html_nodes("a.DY5T1d") %>% 
      html_text()
  ) 

return(news_dat)
}

df <- news('2020', '05')
```

I would like to create a loop which where it takes the argument from Year 2000 to 2021 and for each month. For example the loop will take in argument news('2000', '01') then iterate to news('2000', '02').

I would like to return the dataframe/list for all the headlines in above time line. The code I have which does not work:

```
years <- 2000:2021
months <- 1:12

for (i in length(years)){
  for (j in length(months)){
    temp <- news(i,j)
  }
  newdf <- rbind(newdf, temp)
}
```

Comment: `length(years)` returns a single value. Perhaps you want to use `years` or `seq_along(years)` instead?

Comment: Hey thanks. That makes sense! I changed it to seq_along(years) and  for temp <- news(i,j), I changed it to    temp <- news(years[i],months[j]). Getting the error: "Error in rbind(newdf, temp) : object 'newdf' not found"

Comment: @purple1437 you're getting that error because you haven't defined `newdf` before using it in `rbind`. Define `newdf` as a blank dataframe before your loop and the error should be addressed.

Comment: `newdf` isn't found because on the first iteration of the loop, `newdf` doesn't exist.  By the way, as general rule, if you're using a` for` loop in R, there is almost certainly a better way.  This is a classic case in point.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `library(tidyverse)

newdf <- tibble() %>% expand(year=2000:2021, month=1:12)` is a one line tidyverse solution that gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So I have defined `newdf` however the loop still does not work. I believe it is because the argument has to be in quotes, for example `news('2020', '01')`. Could you suggest how I can put the year in quotes. @Limey My instructor always say "Don't use loops in R" so I'm having some trouble here.  Could you suggest the better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map2_dfr` from the [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package for this.

```
library(textreadr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

news <- function(term, term2) {

  url <-paste0("https://news.google.com/search?q=site%3%2F",term,"%2F",term2,"&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen")
  html_dat <- read_html(url)

  news_dat <- data.frame(
    Title = html_dat %>%
      html_nodes("a.DY5T1d") %>%
      html_text()
  )

}

years <- 2000:2021
months <- 1:12

crossArg <-cross_df(list(year=years, month=months))

df <- map2_dfr(crossArg$year, crossArg$month, news)
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to remember is that R is *designed* to work on columns.  For example, to add 1 to every element of a vector, it's sufficient to write

```
x <- 1:10
x <- x + 1
```

which gives a vector whose first element is `2` and last element is `11`.  So, when you find yourself writing code to loop through *rows* of a vector/matrix/data frame, stop.  There is almost certainly a better way*.

*: There are rare, very rare, exceptions.  This is not one of them.

```
library(tidyverse)

newdf <- tibble() %>% expand(year=2000:2021, month=1:12)
newdf
# A tibble: 264 x 2
    year month
   <int> <int>
 1  2000     1
 2  2000     2
 3  2000     3
 4  2000     4
 5  2000     5
 6  2000     6
 7  2000     7
 8  2000     8
 9  2000     9
10  2000    10
# … with 254 more rows
```

which I believe is what you want.

**Edit**
To forestall OP's request for conversion to character, at which they hint in one of their comments:

```
newdf <- tibble() %>% 
           expand(year=2000:2021, month=1:12) %>% 
           mutate(year=as.character(year), month=as.character(month))
```

or

```
newdf <- tibble() %>% 
           expand(year=as.character(2000:2021), month=as.character(1:12))
```

Though I believe this is unnecessary.